# there is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first. vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
CMD = New SqlCommand("Select * From Jenis where KodeJenis='" & CBjenis.Text & "'", CONN)

RD = CMD.ExecuteReader()
CONN.Open()
RD.Read()

If RD.HasRows = True Then
     TextBox2.Text = RD.Item(1)
Else
     MsgBox("Kode jenis ini tidak terdaftar")
End If
```

what problem ?

Comment: Make sure to close previous connections to the database, please provide us the full error log and the purpose of your class.

Comment: 1st: try to open the connection BEFORE calling the reader. 2nd: close the reader after end if (maybe the connection, too).

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use `Using End Using` syntax to avoid unclosed Connections.

```
   Dim rd As SqlDataReader
        Using CMD = New SqlCommand
            CMD.CommandText = "Select * From Jenis where KodeJenis='" & CBjenis.Text & "'"
            CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            CMD.Connection = CONN
            CMD.Connection.Open()
            rd = CMD.ExecuteReader

            If rd.Read() Then
                TextBox2.Text = rd.Item(1)
            Else
                MsgBox("Kode jenis ini tidak terdaftar")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```